# Rails .where(.... and ....) Searching for two values of the same attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've tried

```
@users = User.where(name: @request.requester or @request.regional_sales_mgr)
```

and

```
@users = User.where(name: @request.requester).where(name: @request.regional_sales_mgr).all
```

This doesn't seem to work.  What I want is to find the user whose name matches @request.requester, and the user whose name matches @request.regional_sales_mgr, and save them both into the variable @users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the general case "OR" queries can be written as:

```
User.where("users.name = ? OR users.name = ?", request.requester, request.regional_sales_mgr)
```

Note: **Rails 5** will support `OR` using:

```
User.where(name: request.requester).or(User.where(name: request.regional_sales_mgr))
```

For this specific case as state in other answers an IN query is simpler:

```
User.where(name: [request.requester, request.regional_sales_mgr])
```

Comment: You should use the more explicit `"users.name = ? OR users.name = ?"` so that joins don't break in the event a joining table also has the `name` column. Or use `.where` as @diego.greyrobot recommends.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the SQL `IN` clause. Activerecord provides a shortcut to this:

```
@users = User.where(name: [@request.requester, @request.regional_sales_mgr]).all
```

Giving an array of values to `name:` will generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN (value1, value2, and so on...);
```

This should find all the users whose names are `@request.requester` or `@request.regional_sales_mgr`

Comment: The following query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN (value1, value2, value3);` is the same as this one: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = value1 OR name = value2 OR name = value3;`, so this does not answer the question.
@sabrams needs the SQL clause `AND`

Answer (score 2):

Diego's answer should solve Sabrams' question without the all in rails 4.x (query for user with a name of x or y)

```
@users = User.where(name: [@request.requester, @request.regional_sales_mgr])
```

For those who find this post like I did actually looking for a rails all, you can chain where's. For instance to only get users that have both of two skills through a join table. (This will returns users with both x and y skill, will not return user with only x)

```
@users = User.joins(:skillable_joins).where(skillable_joins: { skill_id: 1 }).where(skillable_joins: { skill_id: 2 })
```